# Visual Paradigm - import file from Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml

I use `Microsoft visio 2013` and `Visual Paradigm`.I want to import an activity diagram that is created by visio into visual paradigm.[Here, Versatile Output Formats](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/output-export-import/) of visual paradigm says:

> Carry on software design by importing legacy design from Visio drawing
>   (.vdx).

But there is no option in visio 2013 for exporting as `.vdx` file.Also [Introduction to the Visio 2013 file format (.vsdx)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228622(v=office.15).aspx) says:

> Visio 2013 introduces a new file format (.vsdx) for Visio that
>   replaces the Visio binary file format (.vsd) and Visio XML Drawing
>   file format (.vdx)...
>   Developers who are familiar with the Visio XML Drawing file format
>   (.vdx) from previous versions of Visio can find many of the same XML
>   structures within the parts of .vsdx file format.

But how I can get or find `.vdx` file of a diagram in visio 2013 or is there a way to import `.vsdx` to visual paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to send the file to someone with Visio 2010 who can then convert them for you.

Visio 2013 has no Save As .vdx option, Visio 2010 does. So buy Visio 2010 (which is probably not possible now) or find someone who has Visio 2010.

Comment: I tested this way, but did not work.

Comment: Which way? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to import .vsdx to Visual Paradigm?

1. Use "File" > "Save As" > Type "Visio 2003-2010 Drawing (*.vsd)"
2. Use a utilities to convert `vsd` to `vdx`.

   One example online converter is at [Visio Files Conversion](http://www.conceptdraw.com/helpdesk/content/visio-conversion)
3. Import the `vdx` file into Visual Paradigm.

---

#### Save a Visio file as an earlier version

> You can share files with people using Visio 2003 or later by saving
> your diagram file in the appropriate file format.
>
> - Click the "File" tab.
> - In the side bar, click "Save As".
> - Under "Choose a location", click the option you want.
> - Under "Choose a folder", click "Browse for Additional Folders".
> - In the "Save as" type drop-down list, select "Visio 2003-2010 Drawing (*.vsd)".
> - Browse to the location where you want to save the file and click "Save".
>
> If your diagram uses features that are not available in earlier
> versions of Visio, the Microsoft Visio Compatibility Checker dialog
> appears and lists the features that cannot be saved, or that will look
> different in the earlier format. Click Continue to save anyway, or
> Cancel if you want to change the diagram and remove the advanced
> features before you save it.
>
> Applies To: Visio 2013, Visio

Source [Save a Visio file as an earlier version](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Save-a-Visio-file-as-an-earlier-version-7926e2fb-3648-4fbc-b121-9bae2341da25?CTT=1&CorrelationId=a0d1d306-1f0f-4511-b9e3-373524e8a932&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

---

#### ConceptDraw Visio File Conversion

> ConceptDraw Visio File Conversion is a free web service, that is
> available to anyone who has a requirement to open Visio (VSD)
> documents in ConceptDraw PRO.
>
> This service was created for Mac OS users , who need to open visual
> documents saved in Visio(VSD) file format.
>
> The service converts files from Visio binary file format VSD into
> Visio XML files which will then have a VDX file extension.
>
> To use our free file conversion service you should email your .vsd
> file. as attachment. Our automated Visio File Converter will convert
> the file to .vdx and you will be able to view it in 15 minutes or
> less.
>
> You can even send multiple .vsd files to us, compressed in a .zip format.
> Our automated service will extract and convert each file, then send the converted files back to you in the same compression format in which you originally sent them.

Source [Visio Files Conversion](http://www.conceptdraw.com/helpdesk/content/visio-conversion)